# APISIX Gateway - Transfer settings from Integration to Production

Tags: url-routing, gateway, etcd, apache-apisix

We use an APISIX gateway that gets its configuration via etcd.

Is it possible to finish the configuration in one environment (e.g. INT) and then transfer it to the production environment with a click?

It must be noted that other target hosts must be used in PROD than in INT, and that other consumers may exist.

Does anyone see a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

1. APISIX uses etcd to store configurations.
2. According to its architecture (check README: https://github.com/apache/apisix), APISIX is stateless, which means no matter how many APISIX Gateway instances you deploy, they share the same configurations if they connect to the same etcd instances.
3. There has no 1-click migration. You can use the etcd snapshot to save configurations and import them back to production.